# A question about extending solutions of an ODE

Tags: calculus, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose I have two functions $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$, which are related by the differential equation:

$$\cos(x)f_1'(x)=−\sin(x)f_2'(x)$$

I would like to find a solution over $x\in[\frac\pi6,\pi]$ such that for $x\in[\frac\pi6,\frac\pi3], f_1(x)=b_1,f_2(x)=c$, and for $x\in[3\frac\pi4,\pi], f_1(x)=b_2,f_2(x)=c$. The values $c,b_i$ are constants.

I can't see any obstruction to doing this and expect there are many solutions, but I am rather embarrassingly not sure:

How one goes about proving that there are solutions to this problem?

Comment: Please, learn the basic syntax of TeX, because your symbols are a nightmare.

Comment: @siminore for a first time user, helping them is a better way than simply complaining about them.

Comment: @5xum Well, if they can write, I guess they can also read ;-)

Comment: sorry i copied this question from my post on MO (where it was formatted fine, but deemed too low level) and I didn't read how it came out here. However thank you to Siminore and 5xum for alerting me to this and special thanks to 5xum for fixing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the vector valued function $\mathbf{f}(x)=(f_1(x),f_2(x))$. Your condition means that $$(\cos x,\sin x) \cdot \mathbf{f}'(x) \equiv 0 $$
so that the vectors are perpendicular. This means that $\mathbf{f}'(x)$ is proportional to the vector $(-\sin x , \cos x)$, so that there exists some function $\lambda(x)$ such that 
$$f_1'(x)=-\lambda(x) \sin(x) \\ f_2'(x)=+\lambda(x) \cos(x) $$

These two equations can be solved to give

$$f_1(x)=-\int_{\pi/6}^x \lambda(t) \sin(t) dt+A \\
f_2(x)=\int_{\pi/6}^x \lambda(t) \cos(t) dt+B $$

Where $A,B$ are arbitrary constants, and $\lambda$ is an arbitrary function. We would now like to satisfy the remaining conditions:

$$-\int_{\pi/6}^x \lambda(t) \sin(t) dt+A=b_1 \; \forall x \in \left[ \frac{\pi}{6}, \frac{\pi}{3} \right] \\
\int_{\pi/6}^x \lambda(t) \cos(t) dt+B=c \; \forall x \in \left[ \frac{\pi}{6}, \frac{\pi}{3} \right]   \\
-\int_{\pi/6}^x \lambda(t) \sin(t) dt+A=b_2 \; \forall x \in \left[ 3\frac{\pi}{4}, \pi \right] \\
\int_{\pi/6}^x \lambda(t) \cos(t) dt+B=c \; \forall x \in \left[ 3\frac{\pi}{4}, \pi \right] $$

Differentiating the first condition in the open interval $\left( \frac{\pi}{6},\frac{\pi}{3} \right)$ gives

$$-\lambda(x) \sin(x)=0 $$ there. Since $\sin$ has no zeros in that interval we must have $\lambda(x) \equiv 0$ in that open interval. This reduces the first condition to the simple 
$$0+A=b_1, $$ so that we should take $A=b_1$. The second condition reduces similarly to $B=c$.

The same reasoning gives $\lambda(x) \equiv 0$ in the open interval $\left( 3 \frac{\pi}{4}, \pi \right)$ , which simplifies the remaining two conditions to $$-\int_{\pi/3}^{3 \pi/4} \lambda(t) \sin(t) dt+A=b_2, $$ and $$\int_{\pi/3}^{3 \pi/4} \lambda(t) \cos(t) dt+B=c. $$

Plugging in the values we found for $A,B$ gives the remaining two conditions as

$$-\int_{\pi/3}^{3 \pi/4} \lambda(t) \sin(t) dt=b_2-b_1, $$ and $$\int_{\pi/3}^{3 \pi/4} \lambda(t) \cos(t) dt=0. $$

Comment: There is something about your proof that I don't understand. I agree that it is true that the same reasoning implies  $\lambda(x)=0$ in the open interval $(3\pi/4,\pi)$. However I don't see how that simplifies the remaining  conditions. You have written the integral with starting value $\pi/6$. You could re-do it with starting value $3\pi/4$ however that would change the value of $A$ and $B$ and then the argument on the other interval would seem to be invalid. Or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: @thedude once $\lambda(x)=0$ in the open interval, the two integrals in the last two conditions vanish. That's how the remaining conditions are simplified. 

For your other question, taking a different lower bound for the integral is equivalent to taking a different value for the constants $A,B$. I will expand on that if you want.

Comment: No they don't vanish because it is integral from $\pi/6$ not $3\pi/4$ !

Comment: Having said that, I think your idea is really good and can be used to prove that solutions do exist to the original problem, if we just find a $\lambda$ so that \int \lambda(t)sin(t) from $\pi/3$ to $3\pi/4=b_2-b_1$ and \int \lambda(t)cos(t) over the same interval=0.

Comment: @thedude Wow, I haven't seen how wrong I was. I will edit my answer.

Comment: @thedude In order to finish, you could assume $\lambda(t)=a_1(t-\pi/3)^2(t-3 \pi/4)^2(t-a_2)$ in the interval $[\pi/3,3 \pi/4]$ and get two equations for $a_1,a_2$.